# Access permission for Print Merge Documents

Tags: wordpress, permissions, printing

I have CiviCRM installed on Wordpress. I am trying to limit the Print/Merge Document function shown in the below image, to only certain Wordpress roles. Is there such a setting in CiviCRM for this? If not, how else can we achieve this?

[image: screenshot of CiviCRM menu showing print/merge option]

Comment: Hi R John, welcome to CiviCRM on StackExchange. This is entirely run by volunteers who will do their best to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, if you are willing to develop an extension, you need to check https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_summaryActions/ hook to add permission to the "Print/Merge Document" action link.

Something like -

```
function mymodulename_civicrm_summaryActions(&$actions, $contactID) {
  $actions[print_pdf_key_name]['permissions'] = array(...); //your list of permission
}
```

If you need to create a new permission for this task - you need to check https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_permission/ hook as well.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no specific Permission as you have probably already confirmed, therefore this would require a custom extension. If you have the development skills in-house then you may get the required support via https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/dev-newcomers - otherwise you might need to check out a professional development team eg https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors

but you are likely to get some more specific advice on here too if you can be patient.